# Create SQL Server Backup in c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, wpf, database-backups

I'm trying to create sql server backup from my code and do it. but when Path is 
 in drive C:(Example:Documents or Desktop) Can't be created backup. What is the wrong?

```
try
            {
                string DES = GenerateBackupLocation(Destination);
                string databaseName = "MyDataBase";
                Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();
                sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
                sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "BackUp of:" + databaseName + "on" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
                sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "FullBackUp";
                sqlBackup.Database = databaseName;
                BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(DES + "\\" + databaseName + ".bak", DeviceType.File);
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Connectionstring);
                ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(con);
                Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);
                sqlServer.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 60 * 60;
                Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
                sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
                sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
                sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;
                sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
                sqlBackup.Incremental = false;
                sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
                sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;
                sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;
                sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
                sqlBackup.Devices.Remove(deviceItem);
                Message = "Backup Ok";
            }
            catch
            {
                Message = "Can't Create Backup";
            }
```

Comment: You need to catch the exception and see its message to see what is causing the failure. That would be helpful to decide the solution.

Comment: Catch the exception on the `sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);` and the the message is: "An exception of type 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException' occurred in Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoExtended.dll but was not handled in user code"

Answer (score 0):

The most likely situation is that you're trying to back up to a folder that the SQL Server service (i.e. not you) doesn't have permission to write to.

Run SQL Server Configuration Manager, and check who SQL Server is executing as. Check their permission to that path.

Also, rather than all the backup device stuff, etc. you might be far easier just executing a SQL Server command to do a backup i.e. BACKUP dbname TO DISK = 'path' WITH options;

Comment: When Path is other drives that work correct. but when Path is  in drive C:\ the catch the exception.

Comment: Yes, that is likely because of what I described. Have you checked it?